# Where does an IN5408 diode go in a hobby motor, on/off switch and AA battery holder setup?

Tags: motor, diodes

I was told I need to add an IN5408 diode in the following setup but I am unsure where it goes.

2xAA battery pack
Positive to On/Off Switch (simple open close circuit switch)
To small hobby motor

Negative from hobby motor to battery pack

I am not sure if I need to protect the switch, the battery pack or the motor from feedback. I do know which direction the diode allows flow. I just don’t know where to put it in this circuit.

Thanks for any help in advance. Sorry it’s such a simple question but google returns everything way more complex than what I am doing and it confuses me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

The diode will conduct when the switch opens allowing the magnetic energy stored in the motor to be dissipated and not cause a damaging arc across the switch.